# Set up task in gradle to download and generate Java classes from authenticated WSDL

Tags: authentication, gradle, jaxb, wsdl2java

I have got the next task in my build.gradle file to download a WSDL and generate the classes.

The WSDL I am trying to download is authenticated with basic auth. I have got user and password credentials.

How can I set up this task to include user and password if it is possible?

I have copied this task from https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

```
task genJaxb {
   ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
   ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
   ext.schema = 'https://IP/path/wsdl.asmx?WSDL'

outputs.dir classesDir

doLast() {
    project.ant {
        taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
        mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
        mkdir(dir: classesDir)

        xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema,
                package: "package.wsdl") {
            arg(value: "-wsdl")
            produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
        }

        javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.8, target: 1.8, debug: true,
                debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
            src(path: sourcesDir)
            include(name: "**/*.java")
            include(name: "*.java")
        }

        copy(todir: classesDir) {
            fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                exclude(name: "**/*.java")
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that ant's *XJCTask* supports Basic Authentication for retrieving source Wsdl. In your case I would go for a two-step process:

1. one task that downloads the wsdl locally , using **ant.get** task with basic authentication
2. one task that invokes **ant.xjc** with local schema downloaded from first task.

Some guidelines:

**Download task**

Dummy example that retrieves Wsdl from the web (with basic auth, even if this web server does not require it)

```
ext {
    wsdlSrcUrl = 'http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl'
    wsdlLocalPath = "$buildDir/BLZService.wsdl"
    wsdlUser= 'testUser'
    wsdlPassword = 'userPass'
}
task downloadWsdsl {
    doLast {
        file(buildDir).mkdir()
        ant.get(src: wsdlSrcUrl, dest: wsdlLocalPath, username: wsdlUser, password: wsdlPassword)
    }
}
```

**Codegen task**

This task depends on *downloadWsdsl* task

```
task genJaxb {
    dependsOn downloadWsdsl

    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schema = wsdlLocalPath

    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema, package: "hello.wsdl") {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.8, target: 1.8, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```